# Taking inverse of certain rows in dataframe

Tags: r, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of market trades and need to multiply only the put returns by -1. I have the code for that, but can't figure out how to assign it back without affecting the calls.

Input df:

```
         Date  Type  Stock_Open  Stock_Close  Stock_ROI
0  2016-04-27  Call        5.33         4.80  -0.099437
1  2016-06-03   Put        4.80         4.52  -0.058333
2  2016-06-30  Call        4.52         5.29   0.170354
3  2016-07-21   Put        5.29         4.84  -0.085066
4  2016-08-08  Call        4.84         5.35   0.105372
5  2016-08-25   Put        5.35         4.65  -0.130841
6  2016-09-21  Call        4.65         5.07   0.090323
7  2016-10-13   Put        5.07         4.12  -0.187377
8  2016-11-04  Call        4.12         4.79   0.162621
```

Code:

```
flipped_puts = trades_df[trades_df['Type']=='Put']['Stock_ROI']*-1
trades_df['Stock_ROI'] = flipped_puts
```

Output of flipped puts:

```
1    0.058333
3    0.085066
5    0.130841
7    0.187377
```

Output of original DF:

```
         Date  Type  Stock_Open  Stock_Close  Stock_ROI
0  2016-04-27  Call        5.33         4.80        NaN
1  2016-06-03   Put        4.80         4.52   0.058333
2  2016-06-30  Call        4.52         5.29        NaN
3  2016-07-21   Put        5.29         4.84   0.085066
4  2016-08-08  Call        4.84         5.35        NaN
5  2016-08-25   Put        5.35         4.65   0.130841
6  2016-09-21  Call        4.65         5.07        NaN
7  2016-10-13   Put        5.07         4.12   0.187377
8  2016-11-04  Call        4.12         4.79        NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
trades_df.loc[trades_df.Type.eq('Put'), 'Stock_ROI'] *= -1
```

Or

```
trades_df.update(trades_df.query('Type == "Put"').Stock_ROI.mul(-1))
```

both give you

```
trades_df
```

[image]

Comment: I should've used a different column name, should be Option_Type. The data type is just a string.

Got it with this:

trades_df.loc[trades_df['Type']=='Put', 'Stock_ROI'] *= -1

Thanks

Comment: I trust you can can make that adjustment yourself?

Comment: Yep, got it. I like that update, query syntax, thats new to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` from `R`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(trades_df)`), specify the logical condition in 'i', multiply the 'Stock_ROI' with -1 and assign (`:=`) it to a new column.  The other values will be filled by NA.

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(trades_df)[Type == 'Put', Stock_ROIN := Stock_ROI * -1][]
```

If we want to update the same column

```
setDT(trades_df)[Type == 'Put', Stock_ROI := Stock_ROI * -1]
trades_df
#         Date Type Stock_Open Stock_Close Stock_ROI
#1: 2016-04-27 Call       5.33        4.80 -0.099437
#2: 2016-06-03  Put       4.80        4.52  0.058333
#3: 2016-06-30 Call       4.52        5.29  0.170354
#4: 2016-07-21  Put       5.29        4.84  0.085066
#5: 2016-08-08 Call       4.84        5.35  0.105372
#6: 2016-08-25  Put       5.35        4.65  0.130841
#7: 2016-09-21 Call       4.65        5.07  0.090323
#8: 2016-10-13  Put       5.07        4.12  0.187377
#9: 2016-11-04 Call       4.12        4.79  0.162621
```

and want to change the other values to `NA`

```
setDT(trades_df)[Type == 'Put', Stock_ROI := Stock_ROI * -1
         ][Type!= 'Put', Stock_ROI := NA]
trades_df
#         Date Type Stock_Open Stock_Close Stock_ROI
#1: 2016-04-27 Call       5.33        4.80        NA
#2: 2016-06-03  Put       4.80        4.52  0.058333
#3: 2016-06-30 Call       4.52        5.29        NA
#4: 2016-07-21  Put       5.29        4.84  0.085066
#5: 2016-08-08 Call       4.84        5.35        NA
#6: 2016-08-25  Put       5.35        4.65  0.130841
#7: 2016-09-21 Call       4.65        5.07        NA
#8: 2016-10-13  Put       5.07        4.12  0.187377
#9: 2016-11-04 Call       4.12        4.79        NA
```